# How can I get a MacOS Terminal like Ctrl+T command on ConEmu

Tags: terminal, conemu

I'm using ConEmu but cannot find the right command which I can bind to Ctrl+T to get a new tab to open *in the same location* as the current tab (just like what you get in the MacOS terminal with Command+T).

Does anyone know it this is possible?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the "Duplicate tab with current state of root process". Set desired hotkey for it.